# Second Activity not starting in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is the code snippet for starting my second activity.

```
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                val songName = listView?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PlayerActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("songs", mySongs )
                    intent.putExtra("songname", songName)
                    intent.putExtra("pos",position)
                Log.d(TAG, "about to start activity")
                    startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Here is the code snippet that should have worked but didn't work in my second activity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player)

        Log.d(TAG, "Activity Started")
```

Here are the logcat messages.
[image]

The activity is not starting. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you defined you second activity in manifest ? and I think  you should use context.startActivity(intent) to launch  the  new activity

Comment: Try to use activity context

Comment: @AshutoshOjha and Style-7 I tried what you said, not working. (Defined second activity in manifest , tried context.startActivity(intent) and tried using activity context)

Comment: Thank You guys for solving my problem. I don't know why but the second activity's class was abstract.